# Writing "yes" in one column automatically creating information in another

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list with all my students. I want to make it so that if I write "yes" under one of the columns, it automatically adds them to another sheet.

I tried to do a multiple result index match, but I cannot figure out how to do it within multiple sheets.

Essentially, I want to write "yes" in one cell and it will add all the kids that have that "yes" to another sheet so i remember to follow up.

Comment: And what have you done to achieve this? This is not a free scripting site. It is a site that helps people who have helped themselves. So this site can help you with your code if you have any issues with your code. Feel free to share your code and we can help you debug your code. But we cannot code anything for you from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.  Look into the Excel FILTER Function.

On sheet1 I put some dummy data

[image]

Then on Sheet2 I put the formula =FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A5,Sheet1!B2:B5="Yes") which asks Excel to return the values from cells A2:A5 which could be A:A to pick up everything (but that would include the title too) any time the value in column B is Yes

[image]